# Generating Power BI or Tableau native file

Tags: powerbi, export, tableau-api

Is possible to generate/export **Power BI .pbix file** from own app (Java, JS, Python...)? The goal is to export data/PBI file in customer app account and open it directly in Power BI or Tableau.

Is there any library to generate .pbix file dynamically?

Comment: PowerBI has a report authoring library when embedding Power BI in a custom application.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-authoring-overview  Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to acomplish?